# global.asax Application_AcquireRequestState vs. Application_BeginRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

what is the difference?
I would like to implement Language dropdown selection in my app. So when a selected language is selected, a Thread culture would be set and page reloaded.

Like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

where should settings like above be processed? Application_AcquireRequestState  or Application_BeginRequest?

thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the culture data after a user has it set?

Comment: I wold read it from a cookie. so "en-US" would be pulled from a cookie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Application_BeginRequest occurs earlier in the lifecycle and is the 'usual' place this goes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 21):

It depends on the way you are saving your language across requests. If you are using a session to save your selected language in, you should use `Application_AcquireRequestState`, because since `Application_BeginRequest` is *earlier* in the life cycle, the session state object might *not yet be available* at this time.

Comment: Good answer. So you could say (simplified): Culture in Session -> Application_AcquireRequestState / Culture in Cookie -> Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: But what about Controller.BeginExecuteCore (i have a BaseController in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Project)? I used this to set my culture (saved in cookie)

Comment: Just a gut feeling, but it sounds weird to me to use something with "core" in it. The link in the other answer describes the whole life cycle, I'm sure there's a sufficient hook included.