# Stop Async call in Global.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have two mvc applications in one solution.

now i need to maintain session when user redirects from one application to another.

so what my logic is,

- passed GUID in URL.
- get GUID in another projects Global.asax file using Init() method.
- Log in another user.

i done whole code, added below.

now, i am getting call in Init() method but it also calls other methods which are passed in URl.

i.e. call becomes asynch, so because of that, user redirected to other page.

do i need to change my logic or just code?
below is my Global.asax file code.

```
 public override void Init()
    {               
        var userId = Guid.Parse(Request["UserGUID"].ToString());
        if (userId != null && userId == Guid.Parse("1B541D9A-AC3E-466F-897B-6F9033F4533C"))

        //my logic of login management
     }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AshleyMedway : Above code not working as call becomes async, i need a solution that can stop that async call and just run Init() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more then 8 hours of R&D, i found solution that really helped me.

Actually my way is proper but the method is not right.

[Application_AcquireRequestState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975634/global-asax-application-acquirerequeststate-vs-application-beginrequest)

is the  proper method for my scenario.

my code is :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    public void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.Request["UserGUID"];

        if (userId != null)
        {
            Session["UserGuid"] = Guid.Parse(userId.ToString());

            //My logic for session handling..
        }
    }
}
```